# Flutter/Dart/Firestore : How to create subcollections and add data to Firestore?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In the registration part of my App, when a user creates a "familyAccount", I create "an entry" for this account in firestore. It consists in adding a few information concerning the account itself then creating a subcollection called users and add two documents to this subcollection "User1" and "User2" with information. I do this in three steps:

Here's the code :

```dart
final newUser =
    await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: passWord);
if (newUser != null) {
  _fireStore
      .collection('familyAccounts')
      .doc(email)
      .set({
    'name': '$name $firstName',
    'country': country,
    'region': region,
  });
  _fireStore
      .collection('familyAccounts')
      .doc(email)
      .collection('users')
      .doc('user1')
      .set({
    'userId': 'utilisateur1',
    'teacherCode': '',
    'avatar': 'avatar.jpg',
    'vocLists': [],
  });
  _fireStore
      .collection('familyAccounts')
      .doc(email)
      .collection('users')
      .doc('user2')
      .set({
    'userId': 'utilisateur2',
    'teacherCode': '',
    'avatar': 'avatar.jpg',
    'vocLists': [],
  });
```

It works fine, but I am wondering whether this could be done in a single _fireStore operation ?

Also : if I want to update 'avatar' in "User2", what line of code would I need to use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could do this with a [batch write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes), this would be of no real benefit as each operation in the batch counts separately towards your Cloud Firestore usage and the way you are doing it now is less prompt to failures.

For updating `avatar` in `User2`, try using the [update statement](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#node.js_8) referencing the proper doc in the sub collection.